# pandas datetime Series difference not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

The following is a minimal working example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"datetime": 
    [
        "2021-09-01 00:00:01",
        "2021-09-01 00:00:02",
        "2021-09-01 00:00:03",
        "2021-09-01 00:00:04",
        "2021-09-01 00:00:05",
        "2021-09-01 00:00:06",
        "2021-09-01 00:00:07",
        "2021-09-01 00:00:08",
        "2021-09-01 00:00:09",
        "2021-09-01 00:00:10",
    ]}
)
df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"])
delta = df["datetime"][1::] - df["datetime"][0:-1]
print(delta)
```

I got

```
0      NaT
1   0 days
2   0 days
3   0 days
4   0 days
5   0 days
6   0 days
7   0 days
8   0 days
9      NaT
Name: datetime, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

but I though this would be an array with entries of `Timedelta('0 days 00:00:01')`, and in fact if I do `df["datetime"][1] - df["datetime"][0]` that's what I get. On the other hand `df["datetime"][1:2] - df["datetime"][0:1]` produces

```
0   NaT
1   NaT
Name: datetime, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

what am I missing here?

Comment: Are you looking for `df["datetime"].diff()` ? You could also reset the indices of the views you're taking; `df["datetime"][1::].reset_index() - df["datetime"][0:-1].reset_index()`, but I'd suggest to use `diff`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example the index is taken into account. So it will take the same times an subtract them, which then ends up 0 days.
NaT because index 0 and 9 are not present in both Series.

```
df["datetime"][1::] - df["datetime"][0:-1].values
```